# How to make variables from external HTML parse in dompdf?

Tags: php, html, pdf

**EDIT**:
OK, seems I found a solution:

```
ob_start(); 
include $htmlfile; 
$content = ob_get_clean();
```

Apparently file_get_contents does not evaluate.

---

I am trying to get dompdf to work with an external HTML file which contains PHP variables - but it is not working. The variables are not parsed, but output as written, i.e. if I have this HTML file:

"invoice.html":

```
<div>
Hello $firstname
</div>
```

and I use it in connection with dompdf to create a pdf out of it like this:

```
$invoicehtml = file_get_contents('invoice.html');
```

THen when the PDF is created I get the "raw" text:

```
Hello $firstname
```

Whereas $firstname is already defined in the config.php (which is included) as e.g.:
$firstname = "John";

When I use the invoice html code directly in the script where dompdf is created, i.e:

```
$invoicehtml = 'Hello'.$firstname;
```

then it works just fine.

But why is it not working when I use the external HTML file?

I have alrady tried with str_replace, e.g. Have this in HTML file:

```
<div>
Hello {firstname}
</div>
```

Then replace "{" with "$" and "}" with "" - but I basically just get the same thing. At the end in the PDF it says "Hello $firstname".

I have already searched here and on google and found a similar question to this but that didn't solve anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, seems I found a solution:

```
ob_start(); 
include $htmlfile; 
$content = ob_get_clean();
```

Apparently file_get_contents does not evaluate.